# Segmentation fault running IDBA-UD

Tags: bioinformatics

I had run IDBA-UD in four of my metagenome samples and got a segmentation fault error while processing one of them.

The command I used was `idba_ud -r M002_interleaved.fasta -o idba_assembly_M002 --num_threads 10`, and I got the following error:

*/var/spool/slurmd/job67881681/slurm_script: line 16:  3644 Segmentation fault

idba_ud -r M002_interleaved.fasta -o idba_assembly_M002 --num_threads 10*

I have previously runned `fq2fa` in this sample.

Could anyone please help me?

Thank you in advance.